# Show first navigation window by default until others clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently, I am trying to hide Navigation when another button is clicked like below.

```js
var $links = $('nav a');
var $content = $('.navLinks');
$links.click(function() {
  $content.hide();
  $content.eq( $links.index(this) ).show();
});
```

```css
.navLinks {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
    <nav>
       <a href="#1">1</a>
       <a href="#2">2</a>
       <a href="#3">3</a>
    </nav>
</div>

<div id="1" class="navLinks"> content 1 </div>
<p>Some dummy paragraph that's trying to break our index count :)</p>
<div id="2" class="navLinks"> content 2 </div>
<div id="3" class="navLinks"> content 3 </div>
```

However, I'd like for the results of `1` to be displayed until a user clicks on `2` or `3` how can I go about doing that?

Comment: First of all, please go read [ask] and [mcve], and then edit your question accordingly. Code relevant to your question belongs directly in it, in text form, not just dumped on an external site.

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski OP want to display the `content 1` by default. until 2 or 3 is clicked

Comment: just add `$('#1').show();` after your click-function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add different styles for the first `.navLinks` element in css

```css
.navLinks {
  display: none;
}

.navLinks:first-of-type {
  display: block;
}
```

**EDIT**

It won't work in this case.

`:first-of-type` would work if `#1` div would be the first div, but is in fact second after `.nav` div.

So you can set style `display: block` for all `.navLinks` elements and set style `display: none` for all of those `.navLinks` elements that are after an element with class `.navLinks`.

**Here is an working example**

```js
var $links = $('nav a');
var $content = $('.navLinks');
$links.click(function() {
  $content.hide();
  $content.eq( $links.index(this) ).show();
});
```

```css
.navLinks {
    display: block;
}

.navLinks ~ .navLinks {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
    <nav>
       <a href="#1">1</a>
       <a href="#2">2</a>
       <a href="#3">3</a>
    </nav>
</div>

<div id="1" class="navLinks"> content 1 </div>
<p>Some dummy paragraph that's trying to break our index count :)</p>
<div id="2" class="navLinks"> content 2 </div>
<div id="3" class="navLinks"> content 3 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('#1').show();
var $links = $('nav a');
var $content = $('.navLinks');
$links.click(function() {
  $content.hide();
  $content.eq( $links.index(this) ).show();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply add css to show `#1` (use ID's that starts with letters, not numbers) by default:

```js
var $links = $('nav a');
var $content = $('.navLinks');
$links.click(function() {
  $content.hide();
  $content.eq( $links.index(this) ).show();
});
```

```css
.navLinks {
    display: none;
}

#a1 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
    <nav>
       <a href="#a1">1</a>
       <a href="#a2">2</a>
       <a href="#a3">3</a>
    </nav>
</div>

<div id="a1" class="navLinks"> content 1 </div>
<p>Some dummy paragraph that's trying to break our index count :)</p>
<div id="a2" class="navLinks"> content 2 </div>
<div id="a3" class="navLinks"> content 3 </div>
```